# Method Not Found using WCF POST Method

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, wcf-binding

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService1
    <OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", UriTemplate:="InsertData/{name}/{Surname}")>
    Function InsertData(ByVal name As String, ByVal surname As String) As String
End Interface
```

Implemented it

```
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1

    Public Function InsertData(name As String, surname As String) As String Implements IService1.InsertData
        ' Save name and surname which does work
    End Function
End Class
```

My web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfParameters.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:12345/Service1.svc" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBinding"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="WebHttpw"
          contract="WcfParameters.IService1" />
        <!--<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />-->
      </service>
    </services>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:12345/Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfParameters.IService1" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBinding">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--<protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>-->    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I am trying to create a service which will accept a few parameters and save the data to my database.

Using the above configuration if i navigate to http://localhost:12345/Service1.svc/InsertData/name/surname i get the error "Method Not Found"

If i do the same POST method and run it in **Fiddler then it saves to the database successfully.**

I then used this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/26/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work.aspx as a guide but i think ive used as much info in order to accomplish what i think i need (i could be wrong).

Should i be doing something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using the above configuration if i navigate to
>   http://localhost:12345/Service1.svc/InsertData/name/surname i get the
>   error "Method Not Found"

When you do this trough your browser you are actually doing a GET request, which your method does not support.

When you do it trough Fiddler you issue a POST.

You can do a POST using the [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx) class or [HttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) trough your code.

Comment: Any article/example i could follow to see what i need to do (im a little lost)? Ideally i would like to create the URL to accept parameters and then to save to my database. Thanks

Comment: OR are you saying what i have is correct but to the people that want to use the URL have to work out a way to POST data but the URL will automatically save whatever is passed in to the parameter fields?

Comment: @Computer exactly, it is only how clients will use it that matters in this case I think. They need to issue a POST request and pass in the parameters in the querystring to access your method.